# LNK 2005 "already defined in .obj" error during compilation

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and practicing OOPS concepts on VS Code. I am trying to solve a simple problem where the program involves taking two complex numbers and printing out the sum, difference and product.

## This is my header file

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Complex
{
private:
    float real1, img1, real2, img2;
public:
    Complex();
    Complex(float r1, float i1, float r2, float i2);
    std::string calc_sum();
    std::string calc_diff();
    float calc_prod();
};
```

## Implementation file:

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Complex::Complex() : real1{ 0.0 }, img1{ 0.0 }, real2{ 0.0 }, img2{ 0.0 } {}

Complex::Complex(float r1,float img1,float r2, float img2): 
    real1{r1}, img1 {img1}, real2 {r2}, img2 {img2}{}

std::string Complex::calc_sum() {
    float real_sum = real1 + real2;
    float img_sum = img1 + img2;

    string r_sum, i_sum;
    r_sum = to_string(real_sum);
    i_sum = to_string(img_sum);

    string sum = r_sum + " + i(" + i_sum + ")";
    return sum;
}

std::string Complex::calc_diff() {
    float real_diff = real1 - real2;
    float img_diff = img1 - img2;

    string r_diff, i_diff;
    r_diff = to_string(real_diff);
    i_diff = to_string(img_diff);

    string diff = r_diff + " + i(" + i_diff + ")";
    return diff;
}

float Complex::calc_prod() {
    float real_prod = real1 * real2;
    float img_prod = img1 * img2;
    return (real_prod - img_prod);
}
```

## Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.cpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float real_1,real_2, img_1, img_2, prod;
    string sum, diff;

    cout << "Gathering input for 1st complex number..." << endl;
    cout << "Enter real part: " << endl;
    cin >> real_1;
    cout << "Enter imaginary part: " << endl;
    cin >> img_1;
    cout << "Gathering input for 2nd complex number..." << endl;
    cout << "Enter real part: " << endl;
    cin >> real_2;
    cout << "Enter imaginary part: " << endl;
    cin >> img_2;

    Complex obj;
    Complex obj1(real_1, img_1, real_2, img_2);

    cout << "Sum Diff and Product are: " << endl;
    sum = obj.calc_sum();
    diff = obj.calc_diff();
    prod = obj.calc_prod();
    cout << "Sum: " << " " << "Diff: " << " " << "Product: " << endl;

    cout << "Sum, Diff, Prod of entered numbers are: " << endl;
    sum = obj1.calc_sum();
    diff = obj1.calc_diff();
    prod = obj1.calc_prod();
    cout << "Sum: " << " " << "Diff: " << " " << "Product: " << endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

## These are the errors I get:

[image]

I saw a similar question, but the suggestion there was to remove the inclusion of the `.cpp` in the `main.cpp` file. I tried that, but I get compilation errors saying "Complex: is an undeclared identifier".

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Don't include cpp files.

Comment: `#include "Complex.cpp"` should be `#include "Complex.h"`

Comment: Read up on the one definition rule.  Then observe how including any file that has definitions makes it really easy to violate the one definition rule. Make

Comment: Your main.cpp includes complex.cpp.    As a rule, source files (.cpp extension) should not include each other.   They should include headers (like complex.h) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main.cpp`'s contents are:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Complex.cpp"
#include<string>
```

An `#include` in C++ is equivalent to physically inserting the contents of the included file into the including file.

Your `main.cpp` contains everything, every last bit of what's in `complex.cpp`.

Everything in `complex.cpp` gets compiled and linked twice, once by itself, once when inserted into `main.cpp`.

This is a clear fat-finger. You obviously meant to `#include "Complex.h"`, instead of `Complex.cpp`, in order to include only the class declaration instead of the entire kit-and-caboodle.